# Cesium entity drawing itself, and all previously added entities into itself in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, cesiumjs

This is kind of hard to explain so here is a pretty picture from Safari:
[image]

As can be seen in this picture is that each "label" which has a slight transparency shows another label behind it. This happens with every entity on the map.

This is what it looks like in Chrome:
[image]

Nice and pretty!

Has anyone experienced this before? Has a solution been found?

Comment: Can you provide some sample code to reproduce this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using svg's for my billboards. For some reason Safari couldn't handle the rendering of these svg's. I managed to solve this by converting all svg's to png's before setting them as the image of a billboard. 
Hope this can help someone else in the future!